# Why System.String beahaves like a value type? (How to write value type classes like string?)

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a 'Date' class that behaves like a Value Type.
for example, Instead of writing a Clone method for setting properties safely, make the Date class to pass by value:

```
public Date Birthday
        {
            get { return this.birthday; }
            set 
            { 
               this.birthday = value.Clone(); 
            } //I want to write this.birthday = value; 
              //without changing external value when this.Birthday changes
        }
```

I know this is possible because System.String is a class and behaves like a value. for example:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hi";
s1 = s2;
s2="Hello";
Console.WriteLine(s1);  //Prints 'Hi'
```

First I thought writers of this class override '=' operator, but now I know that the '=' operator can not be overridden. so how they write String class?

Edit: I just want to make my Date class to pass it's instances by value, like as String.

Comment: your example with String doesn't prove anything... the result would be the same for all types, reference or value

Comment: @Thomas Levesque - I think this is incorrect.  If S1 and S2 were classes then the output would be "Hello".

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: No! I test it. it prints 'Hi'. and System.String is a class (I look up in Object Browser)...

Comment: Thomas is right. When you do: S1 = S2 you're making S1 point to the same location of memory of S2.

Then with S2 = "Hello", you're making S2 point to a location containing "Hello", but S1 still point to the previous location of memory.
So it' doesn't matter if they're strings, it happens with all classes...

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee, s2 is "Hi" and you assign s2 to s1, so of course it prints "Hi" ! this has nothing to do with String being a value of reference type...

Comment: I am just confused Sorush. Why would you need something like this?

Comment: @Justin: Anything! I'm just trying to learn about reference types and value types... I know that I can overcome by using struct instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public class Date{ ...code...}` would be a reference type...not what you want.

`public struct Date { ...code...}` would be a value type...probably what you want.

The string class is, as it is a class, a reference type...and is immutable..how being immutable effects the behavior of string objects can be confusing at the start.

Given `string s1 = "Fish";` s1 is a reference that points to "Fish"...It is the "Fish" bit can never be changed....what s1 points to can be changed. If you then assign `s1 = "Tuna";` "Fish" still exists but is no longer referenced and will be GC'd.

In your example after: `s1=s2` s1,s2 now reference the same string "Hi"...there is only one "Hi".

I hope I have not gone way below your level.

Comment: +1,Thanks. now I understand what is happening when saying s1=s2. but why other classes have not same behavior? for example if d1 and d2 were 'Date's then d1=d2 didn't do like s1=s2.?

Comment: @Sorush, other *classes* (reference types) **do** have the same behavior. But *structs* (value types) have value semantics, so if Date is a struct, d1 = d2 will copy the value of d2 into d1, so you will have 2 instances of Date.

Comment: Sorush, this happens because string is a reference type where just pointers change. Whereas Date is a valuetype.

Comment: -snip- Exactly what Thomas said.

Answer (score 7):

First, your `string`-based example does not illustrate your question.

The thing with `DateTime` and `String` is that they are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object): once an instance is created, it cannot be changed in any way. For example, you cannot add 2 minutes to a `DateTime` instance by just saying `date.Minutes += 2`: you'll have to invoke `date.AddMinutes(2)`, which will yield a totally new instance.

To make objects read-only, just follow the same pattern.

Comment: define: immutable: `not subject or susceptible to change or variation in form or quality or nature; "the view of that time was that all species were immutable ...`

Comment: I didn't mean System.DateTime class. I write a class named Date, and it's instances behave are passed by reference. i want to pass them by value without changing user-side code.

Comment: Use a struct instead of a class then

Comment: @ thecoop : but the 'System.String' is not a struct.

Comment: Downvote. System.DateTime is a struct, and thus a value type. It is mutable.

Comment: @tc How exactly `DateTime` is mutable?

Comment: @@@@ Who speaks about System.DateTime? I'm writing my own class and want it to pass by value.

Comment: @tc, DateTime is not mutable, and it is not related to it being a struct : both values and reference types can be mutable or immutable...

Answer (score 4):

It's not the '=' operator, it's the fact that when you say

```
stringThing = "thing";
```

you're creating a new string, not changing the current string to something else.